# Can't find USB Codec in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, usb, codec

My Sony turntable requires a USB codec in order to run the Sony Sound Forge Audio Studio 9.0 software included; however, I cannot find the USB codec in Windows 8.  Any idea where I can find a related download?

Comment: more details on your sony turntable please? model etc

Comment: It is a PS-LX300USB Turntable

Answer (score 0):

If the USB Audio Codec is missing from the Sound options when the unit is connected to a computer running Windows® 7 or Windows Vista® operating systems, follow these steps to resolve the issue:

1. Right-click on the Speaker icon in the bottom-right corner of the Taskbar.
2. Click on Recording Devices .
3. Click on the Recording tab.
4. Right-click in the middle part of the dialog box.
5. Set a check mark next to Show Disabled Devices from the list box.
   **NOTE**: Once you have added a check mark next to Show Disabled Devices , you should now see the USB Audio Codec option.
6. Once you have selected Use this device (enable) for the USB Audio Codec option, click OK .

source: http://www.kb.sony.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=C1002760&fes=true&mdl=PSLX300USB

note: guide for windows 7 applies for windows 8, as they share the same software and driver.

Comment: I tried that last night, but the USB Audio Codec option did not appear.  I'll try that again tonight, though, when I get home from work.  Thanks for responding!